# Way to see when 2 web views finish loading? (Cocoa/Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, webview

I'm writing a small program for MacOS that requires 2 web views to be displayed. I need to be able to see when each individual WebView has finished loading. My issue is that

```
func webView(_ sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadFor frame: WebFrame!) { ... }
```

does not seem to be able to differentiate between the 2 views. Is there anything that can be executed exclusively for when each view finishes loading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can identify webViews by `sender` of the delegate method.

I don't know how you implement them, but for instance, just compare with properties themselves.

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstWebView: WebView?
@IBOutlet weak var secondWebView: WebView?

func webView(_ sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadFor frame: WebFrame!) { 

    if sender == self.firstWebView {
        // code for the first one
    } else if sender == self.secondWebView {
        // code for the second one
    }
}
```